Getting unexpected poor performance in influxDB with 17,280,000 records
I have the following setting:
I expect data from a combined sensor at a rate of 200/s. The record consists of acceleration data (a.X, a.Y) and GPS- data (Lat, Lon). In addition there is data from two force sensors, giving data each from two force components (Fle, Fri).
I set the timestamp of the records while writing to InfluxDB, because it is not sure, that the latency of data is always constant. For testing purpose I set the starttime 24 hours in the past and increment the timestamp with everey record with 5 milliseconds. This means, I write 12,280,000 records to the freshly declared bucket. This takes a lot of time, but is faster than realtime (this means, I write more than 200 records/s). The python code is shown below:
import influxdb_client, os, time
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

token = os.environ.get("INFLUXDB_TOKEN")
org = "Institute"
url = "http://localhost:8086"
bucket="Institute-Bucket"

write_client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org)
write_api = write_client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
# Starttime -24h in ms
timestamp = int(datetime.now().timestamp() - 86400)*1000
# (60*60*24) seconds * 200/s => 17280000
for value in range(17280000):
  Fle1 = int(350+700*math.sin(math.radians(value)))
  Fri1 = int(350+700*math.cos(math.radians(value)))
  Fle2 = int(300+700*math.sin(math.radians(value)))
  Fri2 = int(300+700*math.cos(math.radians(value)))
  ts = timestamp + 5*value
  points = [Point("measurement5").tag("SensorTyp", "Vehicle").tag("SensorID", "1000").field("a.X", random.randint(-9, 9)).field("a.Y", random.randint(-9, 9)).field("Lat", 52.465827).field("Lon", 13.504945).time(ts, WritePrecision.MS),
            Point("measurement5").tag("SensorTyp", "Force").tag("SensorID", "2010").field("Fle", Fli1).field("Fri", Fri1).time(ts, WritePrecision.MS),
            Point("measurement5").tag("SensorTyp", "Force").tag("SensorID", "2011").field("Fle", Fle2).field("Fri", Fri2).time(ts, WritePrecision.MS) ]
  write_api.write(bucket=bucket,  org=org, record= points)
  if value % 100 == 0:
    time.sleep(0.01) # separate points by 0.01 second
    print ("value " + str(value))

When testing the query- performance, I used the following code:
query_api = write_client.query_api()

query = """from(bucket: "Institute-Bucket")
 |> range(start: 2024-11-27T23:30:00Z, stop: 2024-11-27T23:33:00Z)
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "measurement5")
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r.SensorID == "2011")"""
vorher = datetime.now()
tables = query_api.query(query, org="Institut FES")
nachher = datetime.now()
print (nachher - vorher)

for table in tables:
    for record in table.records:            
        print(record.get_time(), record.get_field(), record.get_value())

With this I am querying 3 minutes in the middle of the data bucket, filtering for a certain tag.
But this query takes InfluxDB 27s:
>>> print (nachher - vorher)
0:00:27.654377

The machine is a Windows10 computer, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 0 @ 3.60GHz   3.60 GHz, 8 GB RAM.
I didn't expect this to be so slow. So I assume, my too naive approach doesn't use the full capabilities of InfluxDB.
I would like the query time to be less than a second. How can I achieve this?

Crosspost to https://community.influxdata.com/t/is-performance-of-influxdb-oss-enough-for-this-task-12-700-000-records-d/39631

I don't know influxdb at all, but looking at your code I wonder.... Should your org values match? Does it change anything if you remove the first filter condition? Perhaps you should be writing to multiple time series.

Yes, you're right, it should be:
tables = query_api.query(query, org="Institute-Bucket")
I adapted the source for the forum question and overlooked it there. Surely InfluxDB would have been thrown with errors at me if I put there a wrong org- name.

Did you check the cardinality of your records? https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/write-data/best-practices/resolve-high-cardinality/
